# Hard Drive Remaining Space Not Matching up With Current Space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

my hard drive is reported to have 65GB left out of a possible 223GB, however running WinDirStat and doing it via Windows, the hard drive only has about 60GB of used space. Where has the other 150GB of space gone?

I've googled this issue and most answers say some Windows files are hidden, but 150GB of hidden files seems rather extreme to me.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of the drives]

Comment: Difficult to explain this without having the data from `WinDirStat` also.  Just doing properties on the drive counts the same file multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting all files and showing properties skips files where don't have **access to** (like System Restore Point data).

Run [TreesizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) **([as admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token))** (this shows all folders) and look which folders "eat" most space.

[image]

Comment: The lack of running WinDirStat is likely the reason for the reported space difference

Answer (score 0):

it could be what i call a lie file, i once had windows tell me a file was 0bytes, and after deleting said questionable file i freed up over 6gb of space on my drive. my expierence windows is REALLY bad at recognizing files from other filesystems (pretty sure my file was from an ext3 partition... i have no idea how)